# Upgrading Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK from 5.0.5 to 6.4.2 results in linker errors

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, ads

I have an existing iOS app that is using Google Mobile Ads SDK (v 5.0.5, I believe). I need to upgrade it to the latest version for DoubleClick support. However, I'm getting linker errors.

My steps were as follows:

1. Remove file references for previous SDK from project
2. Remove previous `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` linked library
3. Follow the [setup instructions](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) (to the letter, including the required frameworks, including only the specific files, as well as adding the Other Linker Flag)

The specific error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

```
  "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from
```

or

```
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: I also found a reference to the 5.0.5 path in the Library Search Path area of the project settings. I removed it, cleaned, and rebuilt, but I'm still seeing linker issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need the -all_load linker flag option too?  According to this article it's obsolete for newer ARM7 targets, but perhaps you have an old target?

http://vntin.com/feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/LTiVe

See under this section: "Support for armv7s"

"If you’re targeting the armv7s architecture, you will not need to add the -all_load linker flag to your projects anymore. "

[Update]

You can try to verify what's in the lib*.a file by using the nm command.

```
nm -U libGoogleAdMobAds.a  | grep kGADAdSizeBanner
```

Also, clicking on the Log Navigator may provide some additional information.  Select the last icon then your last build in the left nav.

[image]

[Update 2]

Someone on this site also complained about a linker problem with the new API.  Might have to make small changes to your code.

http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/Community/posts.php?topic=1246

```
Something has changed in the latest AdMob SDK. I get the same linker error. I can use an older version of the SDK and this all works fine. Anyone know what could have changed with Ad sizes?

EDIT: Found the problem. There were some name changes to constants :)

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/intermediate

Change the GAD_ ad sizes with:

kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width and kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height
```

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and added the -all_load flag, to no avail. I also noticed where it says they dropped support for armv6, which I removed from the project, also to no avail. (non-feed link to post: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/migrating-to-admob-v62-for-ios.html)

Comment: Did you try building on the phone?  You are getting i386 errors, which means you are running in the simulator.  Also, make sure the flags are on the DEBUG and RELEASE settings.  I've made that mistake myself.

Comment: I've double-checked the flags, and they're there for both debug and release. Building for the device yields the same errors (except for armv7, instead of i386, of course).

Comment: The nm command shows multiple instances of kGADAdSizeBanner in the library file. The log navigator doesn't appear to show anything extra. I've tried adding the -v option to the Other Linker Flags, but that doesn't seem to return anything extra either.

Comment: You've clicked the "Validate" button, "Analyzed" the code and aren't ignoring any warnings in the editor?  Little things I always do in situations like this.  Also, do you see the linker output?

Comment: And you've removed (completely) the library at least once and re-added?  Sometimes Xcode does get confused.  Clean builds sometimes fix problems.

Comment: This is a project I was handed to upgrade the Google Ads SDK. The project worked with the previous SDK. There are a number of warnings, but nothing related to use of the SDK. All of the settings validate, and I have removed the previous library references from everywhere I can think to remove it. I have also cleaned and rebuilt numerous times.

Comment: The API might have changed.  I added another update (2) to my answer.

Comment: I've made the changes for the constant names, cleaned and rebuilt, but I've still got the same linker problem.

Comment: At this point, I would create a new small project and include only the Ad code so you can simplify the problem.  Without viewing the code, build, etc., it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next step to try, but I just now had time. I can start with a fresh project and include the SDK (following the same steps) and everything builds and runs just fine. So I've narrowed it down to some issue with the existing project. I just don't know how to narrow down what that is...

Comment: OK, I finally got it to work! I went to the filesystem and deleted the previous version of the file. That gave me a different error than what I had been getting. At that point, I removed the -all_load linker flag and everything compiled and ran. Thanks for all of your help.